# Display text as HTML from form, shows and dis

Tags: jquery

Incredibly simple. Similar questions have been asked, but I cannot get it to work. I'm an intermediate beginner at javascript, but completely new to jQuery. I just want to capture one text input, into a variable (to use later for an API submission), and for now display it back on the Web page to confirm that I captured it. I'm trying to avoid using javascript to get the value in order to understand jQuery for this.

My HTML:

```
<form id='myForm'>
  Zip: <input type="text" id='zip' />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id='submit' />
  <p id='showZip'>Not here yet</p>
</form>
```

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    var myZip = $('#zip').val();
    $('#showZip').html(myZip);
  });
});
```

Edit: I meant to add, that it does actually work, and I see the HTML briefly, then it resets.

Comment: Please explain the desired behaviour of your code, or the undesired one if something is wrong. This far i can tell you you're not avoiding the form from submitting, the function inside `.click` takes an argument that is the event object, name it `ev`, and call `ev.preventDefault()` so the form doesn't submit and reload the page, or something like that.

Comment: I'm sorry, very poor form, I forgot to add the behavior. I am editing the entry. I think you are getting to my problem. Please see above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `preventDefault();` ([read about it here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp)) which will keep the form from submitting and resetting.

To do so, update your code as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').click(function(event) {

   event.preventDefault(); 

   var myZip = $('#zip').val();
    $('#showZip').html(myZip);
  });
});
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for. I had seen it before but couldn't find it again for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

jQuery and Javascript in general isn't going to be able to persist across page submissions unless it is stored within an element capable of doing so like an `<input>` and then passing that value back into the page when it is re-loaded (using your preferred server-side technology).

Since you already have an element that will hold your value, consider adding a `name` attribute which will allow you to access the value within your server-side code :

```
<!-- The name attribute will post the value in this to a key named 'zip' -->
<input type="text" id='zip' name='zip' />
```

**Regarding Your Code**

Your code actually should be correct, however when your form is submitted that any changes to the markup of the page (i.e. setting the HTML of your `showZip` element) will be erased as seen below :

[image]

You'll notice the replacement is occurring just prior to the actual page being refreshed as a result of it being posted to the server.

Comment: I replaced: var myZip = $('#zip').val(); with var myZip = $('input[name="zip"]').val(); but got the same results.

Comment: and I added the 'name' attribute of 'zip' to the text input.

Comment: Your previous code was fine (however the addition of the name attribute on your input is probably necessary). It's worth noting that this is likely a server-side problem to solve. When you post your `<form>`, a value will be sent up with the `zip` key, which you should be able to read using something like `Request["zip"]`, `$_POST["zip"]`, `params[:zip]`, etc. (your language may vary). Depending on your technology used, you would want to replace the contents of your `showZip` element with the value that was posted to the server, otherwise display "Not here yet". Does that make sense?